# JIRA Plugin running single line of code multiple times

Tags: java, sql, plugins, jira, dao

I have a JIRA listener plugin that captures issue events, checks if it was a "created issue" event, and performs an action. Although for some reason a specific line of code seems to run multiple times before stopping (I know this since specific logging messages are being display several times, which should only be seen once). Here is the jist of what I'm talking about:

```
onCreatedEvent(IssueEvent event) {
     Issue issue = event.getIssue();
     if (event.getEventTypeId().equals(EventType.ISSUE_CREATED_ID) {
         // Build needed object (custom class) -> this is the line running multiple times
         BetterIssue betterIssue = BetterIssueFactory.setIssue(issue).build();
         BetterIssueDAO.createBetterIssue(betterIssue);
         // More code below...
     }
}
```

Idea of what `BetterIssueFactory` looks like:

```
public abstract BetterIssueFactory() {
    private static Issue issue;
    public static void build() {
         // Grabs data from JIRA issue using ComponentAccessor...
    }
    public void setIssue(Issue issue) {
        this.issue = issue;
    }
    // More code...
}
```

My guess is that the DAO (which accesses a SQL server and puts this object into a table) is somehow holding this line of code from properly executing until the query has run to completion. NOTE: None of the code I posted open a separate thread to do this, this is all run in sequence (unless PreparedStatement.execute/executeQuery opens a new thread).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like my initial predicate of duplicate code running was wrong. I did not see where the code could be run multiple times when a specific condition was false. Closing this due to the initial question being wrong.